# ko.validation.group is not working as expected ? Knockout

Tags: validation, knockout.js

I been trying to clear display of all errors onload but those errors should display on further action after load .

I got solution for this but i felt it can been done in a better way

**Working solution:** *This will clear onload messages*

```
ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.MAIN(), function (s) {
       ko.utils.arrayForEach(s.STData(), function (s1) {
            ko.utils.arrayForEach(s1.SData(), function (s2) {
                if (s2.Validation.errors().length > 0) {
                    s2.Validation.errors.showAllMessages(false);
                }
           });
        });
    });
```

Tried usign `group` but stuck with error i.e 
`object doesn't support property or method 'ismodified' in knokcout validation` .

**Not working :**

```
  var result=  ko.validation.group(self.MAIN(), { deep: true });
    if (!self.MAIN().isValid()) { // rightly i am getting isvalid false and also showing my error text under it  .

        result.showAllMessages(false); // error at this line as metioned above. 

        return true;
    }
```

**Additional code :**

```
    function data(){ 
    var inner = this;
    self.name=ko.observable(""); // i have many observables
    self.validation = ko.validatedObservable([
    self.name.extend({required true, //custom validations also written})
    ]);
}
```

But i have this function in observable array which is deeper in `self.MAIN`

*My levels :* function `data` object  is pushed into `self.SData` observable array later this one is pushed into `self.STData` and finally i pushed this one into 'self.MAIN' .

So you can clearly see i am trying to clear messages `onLoad` but i get that error . Actually in the mean time i went into validation script file i found i am getting error at this line

```
 ko.utils.arrayForEach(validatables(), function (observable) {
                        observable.isModified(show); // here isModified is undefined
                    });
```

Any suggestions are appreciated .

Comment: You'll have to provide more code (though as little as possible) for us to reproduce your scenario. Also, I'm unclear whether you have a specific problem or if you're actually looking for a [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: i can assure you i'm not looking for any review and i just want to share my code so just in-case someone can understand my issue better . I added the code please check the edit . cheers